# Separation between Input Groups in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Greeting,

If I have several groups of inputs, and under each group there are a number of parameters, and I want to put a title for each group or at least put a kind of separation between each group and another....

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can now do:

```
//@version=4
input1 = input(true, "Input 1", input.bool, group = "Group name")
input2 = input(true, "Input 2", input.bool, group = "Group name")
input3 = input(true, "Input 3", input.bool, group = "Group name")
```

Sources:
https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/organize-script-inputs-in-sections-and-lines-23321/
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_input

Answer (score 0):

By making an additional input with a title that aim to provide a limit, for example:

```
a = input(14)
b = input(14)
limit = input(true,title="//--------------//")
c = input(14)
d = input(14)
```

Comment: Thanks alex... but there will a check box